# Upgrade SignalR to SignalR 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, signalr

My application is using ASP.NET MVC 5. I upgraded SignalR to SignalR 2; getting the user list does not work after the upgrade.

When I debug `SendUserListUpdate`, I can see the list; however it does not send the list to `hub.client.updateUserList`, while in SignalR 1 it does!

```
 public class User
 {
        public string Username;
        public string ConnectionId;
        public bool InCall;
 }  

 public class MyHub : Hub
 {
        private static readonly List<User> Users = new List<User>();

        public void Join(string username)
        {
           Users.Add(new User
            {
                Username = username,
                ConnectionId = Context.ConnectionId
            });

            SendUserListUpdate();
        }

        private void SendUserListUpdate()
        {
            Users.ForEach(u => u.InCall = (GetUserCall(u.ConnectionId) != null));
            Clients.All.updateUserList(Users);
        } 
 }
```

Javascript file:

```
 hub.client.updateUserList = function (userList) {
  $('#discussion').append('<li><strong>' + userList[0].Username + '</strong></li>');
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

have you checked this

https://learn.microsoft.com/vi-vn/aspnet/core/signalr/groups?view=aspnetcore-3.1&viewFallbackFrom=aspnetcore-2.0

i think that article may help you

Answer (score 0):

**Hub:-**

```
public class User
 {
        public string Username;
        public string ConnectionId;
        public bool InCall;
 }  
 [HubName("myHub")]
 public class MyHub : Hub
 {
        private static readonly List<User> Users = new List<User>();

        public void Join(string username)
        {
           Users.Add(new User
            {
                Username = username,
                ConnectionId = Context.ConnectionId
            });

            SendUserListUpdate();
        }

        [HubMethodName("sendUserListUpdate")]
        public void SendUserListUpdate()
        {
            Users.ForEach(u => u.InCall = (GetUserCall(u.ConnectionId) != null));

            //My Code
            var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<MyHub>();
            context.Clients.All.updateUserList(Users);
            //It's also working
            // Clients.All.updateUserList(Users);
        } 
 }
```

**javaScript-**

```
$(function () {
    var myHub = $.connection.myHub;

    myHub.client.updateUserList = function (userList) {
      $('#discussion').append('<li><strong>' + userList[0].Username + '</strong></li>');
    }; 

    $.connection.hub.start()
       .done(function () {
        myHub.server.sendUserListUpdate();
       })
        .fail(function () { 
        console.log('Could not connect'); 
       });
});
```

you can more about SignalR in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60962819/3557266).